# Most efficient way to store/retrieve static data in dotnet core/razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I need to display some basic information about my app on every page (using _Layout.cshtml)

Currently I am displaying the app version like this:

```
<span>version @(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version)</span>
```

However, I also need to include the database version and some other configuration information (obtained from the database at app startup).

My question is where is the most efficient place to keep this information to make generating the page as fast as possible?  My gut tells me that System.Reflection each time to get the version is slow (but this could be completely wrong).

Would it make sense to save the appropriate information to IConfiguration at app start? Is accessing data from IConfiguration at each page load an efficient way to do things?

Would I be better off using IMemoryCache as described here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Would using the  tag helper make sense here? (https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/cache-tag-helper)

Apologies if the question is a little vague - any thoughts very welcome (including telling me I am worrying about nothing!)

Thanks.

Comment: There are at least n+1 options to do this, where n is the number of developers who view the question. Even the question of “most efficient” requires much more information to be answered well. What kind of infrastructure? What is the SLA on responses? How many requests does the app get in a given period of time?

Comment: @HereticMonkey - fair point, infrastructure for live app is single webserver (windows server 2012). There is no SLA on responses. Currently the request level is very small. It is an 'in organisation' app so never going to be super high traffic. However I would like to write my app so that it will scale as best as possible. I want to avoid making costly requests in _Layout.cshtml where possible. Not necessarily expecting there to be a 'right' answer - just wondering how others may handle this.

Comment: Take a look at the list of “kinds of questions not to ask” on the [help/dont-ask]. Open-ended “how would you solve this” with no right answer are not really on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I agree with @NoahStahl posted below using dependency injection in view to carry your data from database to page. And what I wanna add here is that if the data which need to show in layout is small and seldom to change, why not save them at appsettings.json file, this file can also be [injected into the view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configuration-injection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create a service class that provides the version info, and [register as a singleton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#service-registration-methods). Then you can inject this service into your layout to get the data you want to render as needed.

_Layout.cshtml:

```
@inject IMyVersionService versionService
@{
    string version = versionService.GetVersion();
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<span>@version</span>
```

Because the service is a singleton, it will be initialized once on first access and would be efficient to access thereafter. You could set a private field with the resolved version info in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks @Noah - I hadn't appreciated that by using AddSingleton when registering a service, the constructor for that class will only be called once on first use. This seems like both a good way of doing things and also the 'right' way to do it by injecting it as a dependency.